# How Install pyautogui offline without internet?

Tags: python, pyautogui

My company notebook allows me to install anaconda; however, when I try to install pyautogui by the `pip install pyautogui` command, it gives an error, likely to be blocked. How do I install packages offline?

Can I download the package from my private notebook, send it by email to my company notebook and install it?

Answer (score 1):

Try [download files](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/#files) and then [Installing from local archives](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages/#installing-from-local-archives)

Answer (score 0):

Install python’s library with its dependencies offline
On Local Computer (Internet Availability)

1. On computer that has python and internet connection, run following commands.

> mkdir “package name” && cd “package name”
> pip download {package name==version}

2. Download & install Bulk Rename Utility(BRU), for easier filename extraction.
3. In the current dir, select all + drag to BRU or in the current “package name” directory, right-click and click Batch Rename here.
4. Click Clipboard Copy > Filename + Ext.
5. Paste the clipboard’s content into a new text file named requirements.txt
6. Zip all the file in the current directory and upload it to the targeted remote computer.

On Remote Computer (No internet connection)

1. Extract the files inside the archive into a directory.
2. Navigate to the extracted directory and type cmd then enter. Run the following commands;

> pip install --no-index --find-links .\ -r requirements.txt